# What's the difference in memory allocation between different access level in the JVM?

Tags: jvm, heap-memory, private, protected, stack-memory

I was wondering what was the difference in memory allocation, if there is any, when using the access level keywords `private`, `public` and `protected`.

**Edit**: Is it persisted in the stack or the heap ? Is there any way to control where the data is stored ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no difference

Comment: Thanks. All of them are persisted in the stack ? or the Heap ?

Comment: Java objects are always allocated on the heap as the heap is, by definition, the memory where all Java objects are allocated from. This Java heap doesn’t have to be anything like a heap known from other programming languages. It’s up to the JVM, how the heap is organized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Holger just wondering really, should off-heap be mentioned in such cases?

Comment: @Holger Does the jvm "heap" uses some memory in the stack ? do you know which type of cache is used in the `jvm heap` ?

Comment: Modern JVMs like HotSpot use TLABs (= thread local allocation buffers) which can allocate like a stack (just bump a pointer), but are subject to garbage collection. There is no exact equivalent to the simple view on “stack” or “heap” as used, e.g. in the `C` world. HotSpot’s optimizer also uses Scalarization for local objects. That’s not like allocating on the stack, as it implies decomposing the object’s field into individual variables, which don’t need to form a memory layout at all, e.g. some may get eliminated as unused, others get mapped to CPU registers, etc.Don’t try to match `C` terms…